# Why does JavaScript break after decompressing?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to evaluate a very large JavaScript code. The file has been compressed with JavaScript Compressor and it was hard to understand the code. So I decompressed it using the JSFormat Package of Sublime Text editor. The code is now good to read however, when I run it in browser the code breaks. Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Where does it break with what error message?

Comment: No error messages, but I see the HTML tags and some text from the code in the webpage. Also, no images are loaded.

Comment: Then there's likely to be a broken or missing tag, say a `</script>`. There's no way we can give any more specific advice without seeing the code, but make sure all tags match. Syntax highlighting in a code editor often helps find the problem

Answer (score 1):

If the JavaScript in question runs in a web browser and works in Chrome, consider decompressing it using Chrome's [built in JavaScript beautifying function, "Pretty print"](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/Q7t2U51G7YR).

You can access the pretty printing feature by navigating to the developer console's script tab and clicking the `{}` curly brackets in the bottom left corner of the screen—if they're blue, the feature is on. Chrome's routines are probably more robust than the Sublime Text module's, so you might stand a better chance of getting working code out of it.

If by following the steps above you actually *do* manage to get working, cleanly formatted code, you can satisfy your curiosity by running the output of both code formatting engines through a diff program.